# German number Validation

Tags: angular, validation

How can I validate a textbox for a german value input.

I check the [Validators](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators) documentation, but it doesn't contain any numbers validators.

Sample for German number:

- 0
- 12,5
- 100.000
- 100.000,25

Comment: Instead of giving the 0 as example(it looks the same on every locale... ) let us know how thousands are represented... Thank you!

Comment: Added samples with thousend comma

Comment: You can use the [pattern validator](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrote my own validator:

```
import { Directive, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS, Validator, ValidatorFn, Validators } from '@angular/forms';


@Directive({
    selector: '[germannumber]',
    providers: [{ provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: GermannumberValidatorDirective, multi: true }]
})
export class GermannumberValidatorDirective implements Validator {
    validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {
        let valid = true;
        if (control.value) {
            let numberString = control.value as string;
            // remvoe thousend dots, replace the comma
            numberString = numberString.replace('.', '').replace(',', '.')
            let number = parseFloat(numberString);
            valid = number.toString() === control.value;
        }

        // the value is accessibale under 
        // [ELEMENTNAME].errors,germannumber
        return valid ? null : { 'germannumber': true }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="germannumber">germannumber</label>
    <input id="germannumber"
           name="germannumber"
           class="form-control"
           germannumber
           [(ngModel)]="germannumber"
           #name="ngModel">
    <div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)"
         class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="name.errors.germannumber">
            Nummer entspricht nicht dem Detuschen nummernformat!
        </div>
        {{name.errors | json}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But you don't check for the validity as number with separators? I thought you wanted to check that

Comment: you mean, that I don't check if the '.' are at the correct position?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to say :)